# Using sentinel nodes in Linked List operations

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, reference

I was solving a problem on [Remove Linked List elements](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements) on Leetcode, when I came across the concept of "Sentinel/Dummy Nodes" through the provided solution. Using such nodes is supposed to make operations in Linked Lists easier in certain cases, such as empty lists or lists with one element, etc.

The problem description is -

> Remove all elements from a linked list of integers that have value
> val.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:  1->2->6->3->4->5->6, val = 6 Output: 1->2->3->4->5

The given solution is -

```
class Solution {
  public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
    ListNode sentinel = new ListNode(0);
    sentinel.next = head;

    ListNode prev = sentinel, curr = head;
    while (curr != null) {
      if (curr.val == val) prev.next = curr.next;
      else prev = curr;
      curr = curr.next;
    }
    return sentinel.next;
  }
}
```

Let's consider this linked list -
`1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL`, and the value of nodes to be removed being `1`.

So, the result list should be `2 -> 3 -> NULL` with `head` of this list pointing to `2`.

In this line -  `sentinel.next = head;` we make the `sentinel` as the first node in the list, with it's `next` node being "head", like so -
`0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL`,

- Note that `head` still points to `1` (the first node with value 1 in the list).
- Before the while loop begins, we set `prev` to `sentinel` and `curr` to `head`.
- During the loop, `prev` and `curr` move along the list, both pointing to other nodes in the list. Note that `head` still points to the first 1.
- After the loop, `prev` points to the last node in the list (with value 3), while `curr` becomes `null`.
- However, `head` still refers to the very first node in the list (with value 1), and `sentinel.next` refers to this very node. So, when we run `return sentinel.next` -> we get a reference to this first node in the list (with value 1), whose `next` property doesn't point to any other node. So this is a node by itself.

How does this work correctly then? The `ListNode` that should be returned should refer to the node with value `2`, not `1`.

This is based on my knowledge about how references work in Java. Because, when we start out with this -

```java
    ListNode sentinel = new ListNode(0);
    sentinel.next = head;

    ListNode prev = sentinel, curr = head;
```

We get something like this -  `[sentinel] -> [head]` with `prev` pointing to `sentinel` and `curr` pointing to `head`.

But the problem is that both `prev` and `curr` change references during the list, while `sentinel` and `head` do not. So, `sentinel.next` still points to the old `head`.

### EDIT 1

To make my question clearer, here's a [screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkpvh.jpg). What I want to know is - how does `sentinel.next` refer to the node with the value `2`? At the start, `sentinel.next` was set to `head`, and this didn't change anywhere. So, `sentinel.next` should refer to the original `head` of the list - the node with value `1`.

### EDIT 2

I think I got it now. The change happens in this line `prev.next = curr.next;`

Because `prev` and `sentinel` both refer to the same list element (at this stage), `sentinel.next` gets set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- I guess this might be incorrect:

> when we run return sentinel.next -> we get a reference to this first
> node in the list

- `prev` does not move for the first two values, I guess. Only its link is being moved to the next node.
- Another thing is that sentinel is `final`, does not change:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode removeElements(
        final ListNode head,
        final int val
    ) {
        final ListNode sentinel = new ListNode(0);
        sentinel.next = head;

        ListNode prev = sentinel;
        ListNode curr = head;

        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.val == val) {
                prev.next = curr.next;
            }

            else {
                prev = curr;
            }

            curr = curr.next;
        }

        return sentinel.next;
    }
}
```

- Maybe it would be good to note that also we are not `removing` any values (values are there in the memory), we are just changing the links of the Linked List.
- Finally, we are only interested in the head of the Linked List, which would be `sentinel.next`, we are not interested to see where `prev` is.

#### Iteratively

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        if (head == null)
            return null;

        head.next = removeElements(head.next, val);
        return head.val == val ? head.next : head;
    }
}
```

[image]

The link in between 1 and 1 is still there, forgot to draw that.

Comment: Yes, `prev` doesn't move for the two `1`s, but it does for `2` and `3`, so when the loop ends, `prev` is at `3`.  I added a print statement, and the returned value shows up as "2". Screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/J3DkJSn

Comment: But that **is** my question - how does `sentinel.next` refer to `2`, when it should refer to the original `head` - `1`.